# automatic display address on red marker on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how to i set address auto display on red marker without pressing it? Pasted 
below is my javascript code. Please guys i really need your help. i'm really 
confused with the code, really hope you guys would help me out. Thank you so 
much.

```
        var map;

        map = new GMaps({
            el: '#gmap2',
            lat: 1.289701,
            lng: 103.812879,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 18,
            zoomControl: true,
            panControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            clickable: true
        });

        var image = '';
        map.addMarker({
            lat: 1.289701,
            lng: 103.812879,
            icon: image,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            horizontalAlign: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#d3cfcf',
        });

        var styles =[
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [
                    {"color": "#ffffff"}
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [
                    {"color": "#99b3cc"}
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape",
                "stylers": [
                    {"color": "#f2efe9"}
                ]
            }, {
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {"color": "#d3cfcf"}
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [
                    {"color": "#ded2ac"}
                ]
            }, {
                "elementType": "labels.text",
                "stylers": [
                    {"saturation": 1},
                    {"weight": 0.1},
                    {"color": "#000000"}
                ]
            }

        ];

        map.addStyle({
            styledMapName: "Styled Map",
            styles: styles,
            mapTypeId: "map_style"
        });

        map.setStyle("map_style");
    }());
}
```

Comment: use custom marker and then style it according to your requirement

Comment: What do you mean by "address auto display on red marker without pressing it"?  Do you want the infowindows open by default?  Something like [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/examples/basic.html)?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/187              Hi guys, please refer to the link on top, i'm referring to this quesiton. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes geocodezip, i want the infowindows to open by default without pressing anything on it. Can you teach me what code should i add to set it to default? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the answer from this post, so not my original thought: [Google maps-api v3 InfoWindow automatically open on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342994/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-automatically-open-on-page-load)

Looks like you can create a separate method (in this example called `initialize`). This method will create a new `infoWindow` and load it on page load.

```
var infoWindow = null;
function initialize() 
{
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var windowLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.25,-68.03);
    infoWindow.setOptions({
        content: "<div>This is the html content.</div>",
        position: windowLatLng,
    });
    infoWindow.open(map); 
} // end initialize

google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Comment: Hi mpastore, i'm abit noob here. Can you teach me where to slot in through my code? I tested in on my site but fail, can you please guide me along thank you

Comment: http://stages.a-wan.com/hybridmotors/
Hi mpastore, can you have a look at my website right to the bottom that's my map. When i click in the red marker it will display the infoWindow, but i want it to stay there by default. What code should i add? Can you please guide me along from my code what to add in as i'm abit noob here. Thank you