# Trigger click event on google map location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have search filters in my web page. When ever i search some specific state/county in united states then a maker is placed in the center on that searched location. 
And i have added

`google.maps.event.addListener layer, 'click', (e)`

to display some information on pop up.
Above things are working fine. 
**What i want is that whenever i search for some state/county. Then after placing marker(working fine) it should trigger click event on that searched location.** 
I have tried following

```
map.click(marker.getPosition()) # Not working
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', marker.getPosition()) # Not working
```

Please help.

[image]

Comment: You want the pop up information displayed on default?

Comment: yes. I want pop up to show on default whenever someone search through filters. Right now it works if i click on some location on map

Comment: You need to trigger InfoWindow in the end of the search function. You might want to see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342994/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-automatically-open-on-page-load#10343266

Comment: I have seen it, but i am using my custom pop up(to get info via ajax) instead of info-window

Comment: You need to trigger your custom pop up in the end of the search function. You don't need the google.maps.event.trigger.

Comment: Or you can put it in marker function.

Comment: Actually i have used fusion tables along with google maps. And i update fusion tables as well. But they did not contain all information. So whenever someone click on map location. I send ajax call to my application to get information.